# how to grab line by line input from console in shell

Tags: svn, sh

how to read line by line input from console when you do an svn update.

```
!/bin/bash
for line in $(svn update)
do
    printf "$line\n";
done
```

this will print it word by word. I need it line by line 
ex:

```
A paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/newap.java
M paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/telap.html.
D paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/newap_subdirs.mak.
U paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/ABC.png
```

to grab the above file from console

how to grep the beginning of the file(A M D U) in the above and take action ?

if A 
then svn import file:///
fi

if M
then ..
fi

so on for D and U

Comment: **Which business-task** you try to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
svn update | while read LINE; do
 ...
done
```

Read more for "read" command in shell.

Note that shell variables changed inside while block are unlikely seen out of it (this is shell depended but most doesn't export them).

Another way is to redefine IFS to single '\n' character but this could work not anywhere - it's quite often to see parsing bugs in shells. I'm unaware on bash stability there.

In common, it's better to write such scripts in something more advanced than shell (e.g. Perl).

Comment: +1 for answer `...while read line` -1 for "better to write such scripts in something more advanced" ;-) .. Good luck to all.

Comment: can you please tell me how to grep the file modifiers if it is A M D U inside the while loop? reference above example

Comment: `svn update | while read letter rest;do ...` for the simple case. Note that the first field could be empty, though, or there could be more than a single letter. Better to request and properly parse machine-readable output for robustness.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE_LOG is a file of your choice, it will be named as, for example "svn_update_2012-05-13.1336839745", where the suffix digits after "." is seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'. Or use %N for nanoseconds.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

UPDATE_LOG=/tmp/svn_update_$(date +%F.$s)

svn update > $UPDATE_LOG

while read -r line; do
    filename=${line#* }
    case ${line%% *} in
    A)
        # svn import file:/// $filename ?
        ;;
    D)
        # so on ...
        ;;
    M)
        # ...
        ;;
    U)
        # so on ...
        ;;
    *)
        echo "He's Dead, Jim!"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done << $UPDATE_LOG
```

REMARK:

The above script will have problem with 5th line as follows:

```
A paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/newap.java
M paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/telap.html.
D paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/newap_subdirs.mak.
U paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/ABC.png
  paris/input/hyb/shmc/com//hwmca/workload/eam/tasks/create/res/He_s_Dead.Jim
```